# ios appid '' does not support changes to the 'Maps' feature

Tags: ios, xcode6.3.2

so i'm in codesigning, app id, certificate with 6.3.2 and I get that error.
so I go to the app in developer.apple.com and I don't see a "Maps" selection on the choices for the application.  Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: Your question is unclear, can you post the full error?

Comment: the title is the error in the popup in xcode 6.3.2

Comment: we also don't have anything like maps in our code base at all [like delivery routes, or nearby stores, etc.] and we definitely won't be doing anything like that...it's a healthcare application.

Comment: This is a perfectly legitimate question, and does pertain to programming. I'm seeing the exact same error message when trying to add a device to my developer profile for testing

Comment: The answer about building to a device worked for me as well. This happened to me after changing my bundle id.

Answer (score 16):

It could be a problem with your provisioning profiles if you *just* added the device via Xcode. I resolved it by redownloading all of my provisioning profiles in xcode, then re-running the code on the device.

To redownload your provisioning profiles (xcode 6.3.2):

- go to Preferences in XCode
- open Accounts
- Click 'View Details' for your developer account
- Click the Refresh icon on the bottom left to redownload provisioning profiles

Answer (score 6):

Try to run the code on the device first.
I've seen this error too while signing an app with a new developer account. Once I added an iPhone to this account through Organizer, all errors disappeared.

Comment: This worked for me as well. It happened after changing my bundle id.

Answer (score 1):

My Error was resolved just because of inApp Purchase Entitlement was not correctly configured:

1. I goto ProjectName->Capabilities (just next to the General Setting
   Pane)
2. After then i have saw that there is option fix issue i just click
   fix issues.
3. Then all the error disappeared.

You can also check step by step as well.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Just simply disable map capability (if it is enabled) and restart XCode. And problem is gone. 
If map capability not enabled whatever restart XCode.